# Get Radio Button Field Value in Javascript Function in php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, radio-button

I'm attempting to get the value of a radio button field via Ajax, but
it returns only **'undefined'**.

I'm using:

```
function  fetch_data(id,type)
{
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "fetch_data.php",
            data: "id="+id+"&type="+type,
            success: function(msg){
                         $("#div1").html(msg);  
                     }
    });
}

<select name="data1" id="data1"
onchange="fetch_data(this.value,document.getElementsById('radio1').value"
style=" width:150px;"> 


<div id="div1"></div>
```

will replace with  "fetch_data.php" page div

Comment: where is the rAdio button and setting code int he above snipplet ?

Comment: <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" value="1" /> <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" value="2" />

Comment: i am trying to fetch radio button value 
document.getElementsById('radio1').value

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you have `radio1` as an ID to your radio box and replace `document.getElementsById` with `document.getElementById`

Comment: document.getElementsById('radio1').value  it gives me 'undefined'

Comment: Yeah coz you should use `document.getElementById('radio1').value`

Answer (score 1):

codef0rmer is right,
you got an error in your syntax you wrote getElement**S**ById but it's called getElementById without the S.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<select name="data1" id="data1" 
        onchange="fetch_data(this.value,"+document.getElementsById('radio1').value+""          
        style=" width:150px;">
```